# How to check if objects in an array is null. i.e. the key value pair is null

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

Here is the array of object that consists of null object:

```
arr = [{
  yieldConventionId: null,
  yieldConventionName: null,
  yieldCurveSectorId: null,
  yieldCurveSectorName: null,
  yieldCurveTypeId: null,
  yieldCurveTypeName: null,
}]
```

How can I write a condition for null check for this kind of object.

Comment: So you want a function that would tell you that this object is null, in case al of it's properties are null ?

Comment: whether all the fields are null, I want to check that. So that I can apply some other condition based on that. Any work around is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can null check like this

```
let isNull=arr.some(item=> (item.yieldConventionId === null || item.yieldConventionName === null || item.yieldCurveSectorId === null|| item.yieldCurveSectorName === null || item.yieldCurveTypeId === null || item.yieldCurveTypeName === null));
```

This will set your `isNull` to `true` if any of your value is null. You can change `||` to `&&` if you want to check if all values are null.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if any of the value is not Null, here is am Returning an Array with true, false, true when at least one is not null. I have used [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const arr= [{
    'yieldConventionId': null,
    'yieldConventionName': null,
    'yieldCurveSectorId': null,
    'yieldCurveSectorName': null,
    'yieldCurveTypeId': null,
    'yieldCurveTypeName': null
   },
   {'yieldConventionId': null,
    'yieldConventionName': null,
    'yieldCurveSectorId': 'some value',
    'yieldCurveSectorName': null,
    'yieldCurveTypeId': null,
    'yieldCurveTypeName': null
   }
   ];
   
const isAllNotNull = arr.map(function(ob) {
  return Object.keys(ob).some(function(k){
    return ob[k] !== null
   });
});

console.log(isAllNotNull)
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately, Object.values doesnt support es5. Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in ES5, here is an explicit version using multiple `for` loops. It uses array [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check if all the elements of an array (the object values in our case) are `null`.

```js
arr = [
  {
    yieldConventionId: null,
    yieldConventionName: null,
    yieldCurveSectorId: null,
    yieldCurveSectorName: null,
    yieldCurveTypeId: null,
    yieldCurveTypeName: null
  },
  {
    yieldConventionId: null,
    yieldConventionName: null,
    yieldCurveSectorId: null,
    yieldCurveSectorName: 'not null',
    yieldCurveTypeId: null,
    yieldCurveTypeName: null
  },
];

const allNull = array => {
  let result = [];
  for (const elem of array) {
    elemArr = [];
    for (const item in elem) {
      if(elem.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        elemArr.push(elem[item]);
      }
    }
    result.push(elemArr.every(item => item === null));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(allNull(arr));
```